# AuthSub target path prefix does not match the provided "next" URL

Tags: https, google-calendar-api, authsub

Here is my call: `AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl(next, scope, secure, session)`, where
`next = "https://mydomain.com/googleData";
scope = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/";
secure = true;
session = true;`

My registered AuthSub target path prefix is http://mydomain.com. So, the problem is whenever i use https for next URL i am getting to "AuthSub target path prefix does not match the provided "next" URL" page. But it works well with http. 
My application uses both http and https, how can I work around this? As I cannot register my domain with both http and https. I have tried to change the target prefix to https://mydomain.com. It works for both now, but one thing I don't like now is whenever a user uses http after google's "Access Consent" page it is redirected to https... What I want is the users to stay at http if they were using http and vice versa. Can someone help me?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved the problem as follows:
First, I set the target path URL to https:
Second, before calling AuthSubUtil.getRequestUrl() i changed the next parameters value to start with https:// event though the request is coming from http
Third, in order to redirect to the right protocol whether to http or https after Google Consent Page, i use the value i set in the cookie for protocol.

That's it.